# Yet another "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET WebPages Website and am receiving the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
> Data Provider.  It may not be installed.'

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ALMSTEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "EmailAddress", autoCreateTables: true);

<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ALMSTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ALMST;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
```

I have searched tirelessly and tried numerous approaches to solving this. This error seems to be very common with many different answers, but none of them have worked for me. This is not a duplicate, because all the other answers provided on this site, and others, have not resolved my issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: based on your settings, this looks like you are NOT using a server based edition of sql, but the imbedded "CE" version. This of course is not installed by default on most web servers. So, I suspect this works on your local machine, but fails after publishing. I would re-install sql "ce" edition, but MUCH better would be to adopt sql express, or some "non" file based data engine.

Comment: I've tried all versions of SQL Server because I've tried literally everything to get this working. I've even tried opening a once-previously-working project which now no longer works and produces the same error. This is leading me to believe that some installation is screwed or something.

Comment: I have a solution. Am posting an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the connection string from the question with the following solved this for me:

```
<add name="ALMSTDB" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-99CRCTP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ALMST;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

using the following providers:

```
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
```

Comment: In other words, you NOT using the CE, or so called compact "file" edition of SQL engine, but now have installed SQL server express, and are now using a server based database as compared to a FILE based "CE" edition of sql server then, right? If you not using sql "CE" which is a file based system say like ms-access or foxpro? I would remove that reference to CE. To be fair, it possible you did not realize the difference between sql server, and that of the CE edition.  CE edition is simular to sqlLite - it not a server based system.